# How to unit-test that spring @Transactional is present?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, transactions, spring-transactions

I wonder how can I make unittest to ensure that all my DAOs have `propagation=MANDATORY`.
I have implemented just a unit test to call `dao.getAll()` without a transaction, and fail if there was no exception. But this is not kind of full test, I can't check it for all child methods.

That's what I have now:

```
String[] beanNamesForType = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(Dao.class);
for (String beanName : beanNamesForType) {
    Dao bean = (Dao) applicationContext.getBean(beanName);

    try {
        bean.getAll();
        fail();
    } catch (IllegalTransactionStateException ex) {
        //This is expected
    }
}
```

Are there possibility just to check that all DAO methods are proxified with needed transaction propagation? Maybe to use reflection?

Comment: I made a reply, please be aware that this becomes an integration test as the container config is being tested (not a unit test). usually the service layer is transactional and not the DAOs, but making write methods MANDATORY seems like a good idea as a precaution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do it using the following JUnit Test Case:

```
/**
 * Test if all the @Services bean are annotated with the @Transactional
 * annotation.
 */
@Test
public void testServicesTransactionalAnnotations(){
    String[] beansNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String beanName : beansNames){
        Service serviceAnnotation = applicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName, Service.class);
        if(serviceAnnotation != null && applicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName,
                Transactional.class) != null){
            Transactional transactional = applicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName,
                    Transactional.class);
            if(!transactional.propagation().equals(Propagation.MANDATORY)){
                sb.append("Missing @Transactional Annotation in bean:").append(beanName).append("\n");
            }
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(sb.toString(), StringUtils.isBlank(sb.toString()));
}
```

It checks that all the beans annotated with @Service are marked as Transactional too. I use the String Builder to be able to know which beans are missing the annotation.

Comment: Edited to add the search for the Propagation value.

Comment: In case you want it for your DAOS replace the Service annotation with the Repository one in the code.

Comment: That's nice, but it works only for annotations on class. Doesn't work for method annotations.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with an assertion utility method that uses TransactionSynchronizationManager class.

Check methods like [TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionIsolationLevel](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html#getCurrentTransactionIsolationLevel%28%29) and ´isActualTransactionActive´.

It´s possible to get the transaction resource from the thread bound resource map, see the code for [JtaTransactionManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.java) and OpenEntityManagerInViewListener classes in spring source code.